# Do you have to specify a custom font on each CSS page?

Tags: css, fonts, styling

I want to use a custom font on my website. I am using the custom font on one CSS sheet and I have already specified it with

```
@font-face{

}
```

I'm using the same font on another CSS page. Do I have one again specify the font with the @font-face on the other CSS page? Or is specifying it on just one styling sheet enough?

Comment: as long as the external stylesheet is included on your page, font will remain the same.

Comment: I think it depends on what exactly you mean by "a CSS page".

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "CSS pages". There are HTML pages, which can use CSS stylesheets. You write a stylesheet that includes your `@font-face` rules as well as normal styling rule, and then include those on your HTML page using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourstylesheet.css">
```

and you add that to every HTML page that needs to load that particular set of CSS instructions. So, say you have two pages, "index.html" and "about.html", both html files need that `<link...>` code.

(Also note that in HTML5, there is no `.../>` or `...></link>` at the end of that)

Comment: I know, poor choice of words. That's not what I meant. I have a few styling sheets for one single HTML page (I didn't want want too many lines of code on piled up in one file). Say I have a pricing table that has a stylesheet of its own (call it section1.css), and a couple of other divs that are stylised on a different css sheet (call it section2.css). If I used a custom font for section1.css and I used the SAME custom font for section2.css, do I have to insert "@font-face" for BOTH stylesheets? Or should inserting it in just one of them enough? That's basically my question.

Comment: That's probably worth deleting the question over, because that's covered by most tutorials that explain how to use separate .css files on a page. Short answer: no. CSS gets loaded without any information of "What file it came from", all the rules are simply aggregated, with conflicts (redeclarations, etc) resolved using the extremely simply "last seen code wins" rule.